# format text of Label

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I have a label in a view that is controlled by a integer property, when the value is negative it displays with a minus sign, when the value is positive it does not. However, I would like the Label to display "+5", "-3" ...

take the following code as an example

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty
import tornadofx.*

class MyView : View() {

   val negProp = SimpleIntegerProperty(-3) // this prop is in a ItemViewModel
   val posProp = SimpleIntegerProperty(+4) // this prop is in a ItemViewModel

    override val root = hbox {
        label(negProp)      // shows - 3
        label(posProp)      // shows 4
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can format the text once the property changes ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a stringbinding which holds the value you want to display in the label and then bind the label's value property to that:

```
val prop = SimpleIntegerProperty(1)
val propDesc = prop.stringBinding { "%+d".format(it) }
```

Now you can do:

```
label(propDesc)
```

The label will update whenever the property changes value.

You can of course also inline it:

```
label(prop.stringBinding { "%+d".format(it) })
```